# Receiving data from lua tcp socket without data size

Tags: sockets, tcp, lua

I've been working in a socket tcp connection to a game server. The big problem here is that the game server send the data without any separators - since it sends the packet lenght inside the data -, making impossible to use socket:receive("*a") or "*l". The data received from the server does not have a static size and are sent in HEX format. I'm using this solution:

```
while true do
    local rect, r, st = socket.select({_S.sockets.main, _S.sockets.bulle}, nil, 0.2)
    for i, con in ipairs(rect) do
        resp, err, part = con:receive(1)
        if resp ~= nil then
            dataRecv = dataRecv..resp
        end
    end
end
```

As you can see, I can only get all the data from the socket by reading one byte and appending it to a string, not a good way since I have two sockets to read. Is there a better way to receive data from this socket?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is any other option; usually in a situation like this the client reads a packet of specific length to figure out how much it needs to read from the rest of the stream. Some protocols combine new line and the length; for example HTTP uses line separators for headers, with one of the headers specifying the length of the content that follows the headers.

Still, you don't need to read the stream one-by-one character as you can switch to non-blocking read and request any number of characters. If there is not enough to read, you'll get partially read content plus "timeout" signaled, which you can handle in your logic; from the [documentation](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/tcp.html#receive):

> In case of error, the method returns nil followed by an error message
>   which can be the string 'closed' in case the connection was closed
>   before the transmission was completed or the string 'timeout' in case
>   there was a timeout during the operation. Also, after the error
>   message, the function returns the partial result of the transmission.

Comment: Thank you! I was pretty confused about settimeout, looks like the delay can't be lower than 0.3